# Getting 405 error while connecting to JIRA using tJiraInput component

Tags: jira, talend

I have been using TOS 8.0 to develop a job which uses tJIRAInput component to fetch data from JIRA based on JQL.

[image]

It was running fine till Dec 1, but when I checked on Dec 4, job is giving below error:

`Exception in component tJIRAInput_1 (J_testJira_conn) java.lang.RuntimeException: Host validation failed for URL: https://jira.constellation.soprasteria.com/ Connection is established, but status code is 405`

There has not been any change in the job or on my access to JIRA. What could be the issue here? Will appreciate any insight.

I am waiting on another set of credentials to try and test connectivity. I am able to login to the JIRA portal using my own cred, but not via the Talend job anymore.